# Replacing mechanical disc brake with hydraulic

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I need to setup a hydraulic disc brake set on my bike. I've already tried to do it, but I've had some problems like oil leakage, a caliper problem, and it brakes suddenly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If oil leaks from hydraulic line and caliper connection, you can try to wrap some PVC tape around ferrule. At least this is what helped with my BR-RS785.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. As written, this basically asks to troubleshoot any hydraulic disc brake problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently built up a fat bike frame, brakes were shimano saints hydraulic.  I'd never even bled a hydraulic set prior to this.  YouTube videos really made the whole process easy.  I looked over numerous videos on installing hydraulics, saved the few I thought were comprehensive. Installed the brakes while watching the video, step by step.  Worked out well for me.   Sorry I can't give you a specific answer, but your questions were somewhat vague.

Comment: I get you don't have the rep to comment but this is not an answer